# Duplicating row in database with list in input

Tags: pentaho, pdi, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to duplicate row in database input based on list.

Input: I have JSON string which currently getting sorted in db as per fields.

```
 "product": [{"startDate": "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z", "modifiedOn": "2015-03-17T14:12:46.758Z", "parts": ["65", "37"]}]
```

on in database table fields are saved as startdate, modifiedon and parts.
but in parts the values in database is "65","37". What am trying is to split it and it should save two rows in database first row part value will be 65 and second row parts will be 37

Current :

```
startDate      | ModifiedDate       | parts

---------------|--------------------|-------

2015-02-01|2015-03-17               |"65","37"
```

How it should be..

```
startDate      | ModifiedDate       | parts

---------------|--------------------|-------

2015-02-01|2015-03-17               | 65
2015-02-01|2015-03-17               | 37
```

Can some one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "split fields to row" steps to achieve this. Where you need to seletc the field"parts" and delimiter as ",".